# Convert text file like pdf to audio

Tags: flutter, text, flutter-layout, flutter-web, voice

Is it possible to create a program that converts a text file like pdf to audio with flutter

I can write text and turn it into sound, but the problem is that I want to recover the file from storage in any format and to convert it within the program to sound

Comment: Did you find any solution? If yes ,then plz post that in answer